# Vue 3 router changing <routing-view/> but not URL

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, url-routing

I'm having a problem with routing in my vue project, vue-router is working in the `<router-view />` but isn't changing the URL.

Here is what my **main.js** looks like:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createMemoryHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import EditComponent from "./components/EditComponent/EditComponent.vue";
import LoginComponent from "./components/LoginComponent/LoginComponent.vue";

import "./styles/main.scss";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createMemoryHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: "/", name: "Login", component: LoginComponent },
    { path: "/edit", name: "Edit", component: EditComponent },
  ],
});

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-link to="/">Login</router-link>
  <router-link to="/edit">Edit</router-link>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

If I press any `<router-link>` it shows the corresponding component but does not change the URL. And if I go to `http://localhost:5173/edit` it incorrectly shows the `Login` component. Essentially the URL is not working whatsoever for routing, but the router itself is.

For context this Vue project was made with Vite and is in a `frontend` folder of a git repo (I have a node.js server in a `backend`). Also the reason why I have components separated into folders is because I prefer to have the scripts separated from the `<template>`

I am getting no console errors. I have looked at many Vue routing tutorials to see if there is something I'm missing but I cant find any problems. I have not been able to find any similar situation either.

Comment: This is what createMemoryHistory does. If you want the behaviour you describe, use the different history adapter